# WordPress wp-login.php cookie error (WordPress Version 4.2.9)

Tags: cookies, wp-login-form

Error:

> Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

How do I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use your FTP client or cPanel:

- Open file `style.css`
- Rename the Active theme before updating.
- Successfully logged in.
- Change back to the original Theme.